# lazy-evaluation in Xtensor

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, xtensor

In the following function using *xtensor*, I was expecting the compiler to express the computation graph to `auto z = 3.0 * u + 100 * xt::cos(u);` and evaluate the result at `xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> out = z;` when assigning the expression to an exact tensor.

```
template<typename T, size_t nn>
T func_cos(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {

    auto z = 3.0 * u;
    for (auto k = 0; k < 100; ++k){
        z += xt::cos(u);
    }
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> out = z;
    return out(0);
}
```

However, I got an error

```
views_xtensor.cpp:76:11: error: no viable overloaded '+='
        z += xt::cos(u);
[....]
```

Did I use `auto` in an wrong way? How could I use lazy evaluation in a for-loop?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `error: no viable overloaded` Could you please post _all_ related error messages including all the `note:` messages and others from your compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
auto z = 3.0 * u
```

The type of `z` encodes the operation, it is something like

```
xfunction<multiplies, scalar<double>, xtensor_fixed>
```

This class does not hold any value, so it is not possible to assign it anything (even if it is a computed assignment). Now even if iw was possible, consider the following expression

```
auto y = z + xt::cos(u);
```

The type of this expression is something like

```
xfunction<plus, type(z), xfunction<cos, xtensor_fixed>>
```

So when you write

```
z += xt::cos(u); // equivalent to z = z + xt::cos(u);
```

You try to assign `z` something of a completely different type.

Lazy evaluation cannot be used in for loops for these reasons.